# How to take input for a web service in java

Tags: java, php, apache, web-services, input

I am trying to write a simple web service that must take a number as input and return details corresponding to it.

Here is my code that I have written till now.

```
package webserviceapp;

import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

@WebService
public class WebServiceApp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://10.100.66.28:3306/dbname";

//  Database credentials
static final String USER = "user";
static final String PASS = "pass";

static Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Connection conn;
Statement stmt;

try{
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "Select * from table";
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            //do something
        }

}catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
}



}

@WebMethod(action = "returnDetails")
public static String[] returnDetails(int k) throws notFoundException{
    //do the work
    //returns String[]
}

private static class notFoundException extends Exception {

    public notFoundException(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
        System.err.println(s);
    }
}
```

}

I do not know how to take input for the above web service. I have a html page that has a text box and submit button for which I get values through a php code. I want to tunnel this number as input to my web service. Can anyone tell me how can I proceed.
Also, I want the output String[] to be returned to php code so it can be displayed on the html page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it in the URL and from the url you can get the values in java

Comment: Can you elaborate. This is currently the only file I have.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/ this link will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Working off the assumption that you are looking to invoke a RESTful service, there are multiple ways of obtaining input parameters. You can refer to the below article for the ways to achieve this - 
http://www.java4s.com/web-services/how-restful-web-services-extract-input-parameters

Code examples for each are available at http://www.java4s.com/web-services/

Another good article you can refer to is - https://vrsbrazil.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/passing-parameters-to-a-restful-web-service/